# Solid and Liquid Equilibrium

Tags: equilibrium

I understand why solids and liquids are not included in the $K_{eq}$ expressions. However, I'm wondering what the $K$ value for a reaction involving only solid or liquid reactants and products looks like. Theoretically, it'd be 1 no matter what since $1^n = 1$. Is this right? Also, do all such reactions go to completion?

Comment: No, it definitly isn't.

Comment: So then what is it?

Comment: Related: [Why do liquids and solids have constant concentrations?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5520/why-do-liquids-and-solids-have-constant-concentrations?rq=1), [Why are solids and liquids not included in the equilibrium constant? What about in a reaction rate calculation?](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14058/why-are-solids-and-liquids-not-included-in-the-equilibrium-constant-what-about?rq=1)

Comment: These do not address my question. I get that liquids and solids have non-variable concentrations and thus can be considered contributors to $K_{eq}$ via rearrangement, and thus they are not part of the changing expression. What is the K value for A + B --> C + D where A, B, C, and D are solids or liquids?

Comment: If they concentrations don't change, they aren't reacting and indeed you have K=1.

Comment: Mithoron - this is not a duplicate. That question has nothing that addresses what I'm asking.

Comment: If something is reacting it's concentration will change, although it can be neutralised by regeneration, or external addition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate an equilibrium constant at a given temperature for a reaction from the standard free energy change ($\Delta G^{\circ}$) for any reaction using:

$\Delta G^{\circ} = -RT \ln K$

$\Delta G^{\circ}$ can be calculated for reactions using tabulated standard free energies of formation ($\Delta G_{f}^{\circ}$) using the following equation:

$\Delta G^{\circ} = \sum{\Delta G_{f}^{\circ} \mbox{(Products)}} - \sum{\Delta G_{f}^{\circ} \mbox{(Reactants)}}$

If the reaction only contains solids and liquids, then K will still depend on the ratio between the product and reactant concentrations.  However, these concentrations will not change as a reaction moves towards equilibrium, which implies that the reaction quotient ($Q$) remains constant